# How to include an extra AngularJS module (async loaded) in my app/module after load?

Tags: angularjs

I want to include a .js file only before a certain action. This .js contains a new module. I can't include that module in my app's module because it doesn't exist yet when page loads.

*To be specific:*
I'm loading asynchronously `CKEditor` and `ng-ckeditor` in a 'resolve' of a router. The editor file is huge and I don't need it for the entire app. `ng-ckeditor` defines a module. I want to include that module in my app after the .js files load.

Possible?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/stu-salsbury/angular-couch-potato

Comment: It shows how to load things on your *own module* async, not another module.